# Java - Unable to create a file

Tags: java, linux

I am in a Linux Envirnomnet. I am also using Netbeans. Here is my code below:

```
import java.io.*;


public class myFirstJavaProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      File file = new File("home/gk/Hello1.txt");
      // creates the file
      file.createNewFile();
      // creates a FileWriter Object
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this question some how a permissions issue?

Comment: Try adding a slash before "home": `"/home/gk/Hello1.txt"`

Comment: This is likely a permissions issue.  Try creating the file in your home directory

Comment: nope that doesnt work

Comment: If you are using linux you should add ROOT as initial in your PATH.
e.g. `/home/gk/Hello1.txt`
And also check that you have WRITE permission on `gk` directory?

e.g. `$> ls -l`

Comment: Is this writable: drwx------ 55 gk   gk   4096 Jun 24 23:38 gk

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a slash before home. It is looking for a folder that most likely does not exist inside the classpath.

**EDIT**
After you pointed out the exception you were receiving I realized that a checked exception is not being handled. You need to catch the possible `IOException` or include the exception in the method signature.

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
Unhandled exception type IOException myFirstJavaProgram.java /myFirstJavaProgram/src line 22 Java Problem

Comment: Oh whoops, I see. Java has a system called checked Exceptions. You need to say that the method throws the exception or try to catch it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Ashwin Parmar
 */
public class myFirstJavaProgram  {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("/home/gk/Hello1.txt");
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        // creates a FileWriter Object
    }
}
```

When dealing with any File IO action in Java, it is always best to use a try/catch loop

Comment: question. why is the try/catch needed? is there a way to run this progrram with try/catch?

Comment: when dealing with any FileIO action in Java, it is always best to use a try/catch loop.

Comment: If you are trying to run the program without `Try Catch` it will thrown `IOException` for that You must handle that exception by using Try/Catch.

Answer (score 0):

Error in your path.
This `home/gk/Hello1.txt` should be `/home/gk/Hello1.txt`

Comment: the path corresponds to gk user home directory. Do you have gk user? if you have then definitely it is permission issue.